# Three Line Icon/Hamburger Icon style like google chrome toolbar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, hamburger-menu

Hi I need some help to show hamburger icon as it is in google chrome tool bar. I used unicode character &#9776 to display the icon which is kind of fine but I need some help on its styling. esp - when you hover on the icon on chrome it's get highlighted with a border. I have attached a screen shot.

I want to achieve the same style in my application.

This should work on IE 8 and above and google chrome. Any help would be much appreciated..[image: Chrome-HamburgerIcon]

Here is some of code I have tried ..

```css
#HamburgerMenu a:link,
#HamburgerMenu a:hover,
#HamburgerMenu a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:Gray;
    margin-top:8px;
    display:block;
    cursor:default;
    margin-left:1.5px
    
}

#HamburgerMenuLink:hover
{
    z-index:1000;
    border:0px groove gray;
    /*outline-style:outset;*/
   background-color:#d3d3d3;
}
```

```html
<a id="HamburgerMenuLink">&#9776;</a>
```

I am not able to achieve the way it has been done in chrome...

Comment: Provide some code as to what your doing.

Comment: i updated question with my code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```css
#HamburgerMenu a:link,
#HamburgerMenu a:hover,
#HamburgerMenu a:visited
{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:Gray;
    margin-top:8px;
    display:block;
    cursor:default;
    margin-left:1.5px
    
}

#HamburgerMenuLink{
  padding: 5px;
}
#HamburgerMenuLink:hover
{
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<a id="HamburgerMenuLink">&#9776;</a>
```

Comment: This is working fine in chrome but not in IE8. I need to do this for IE8.